# Creating a new contact using Google Inbox

Tags: google-contacts, inbox-by-gmail

Is there a method to create a new contact from Google Inbox? There seems to be other ways to do this, such as the People app on an Android device or via Gmail. However, is there something I'm missing in Google Inbox? (It doesn't seem to exist on the web or on the Android application.)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be, no. Remember, it's still in private review. There's lots of functionality for them to add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can’t **at the moment**. To manage your contacts you have to use Google Contacts, at https://www.google.com/contacts.

On Android:

> #### Manage contacts
>
> If you sync your Google Contacts, you can add, edit, and delete contacts using the People or Contacts app on your phone. Just make sure your contact is stored as a "Google Contact" when you add or edit.
>
> You can also manage your contacts at [www.google.com/contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts).

On iPhone:

> #### Manage contacts
>
> You can manage your contacts at [www.google.com/contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts).
>
> You can also sync your Google Contacts with your iPhone.

On desktop:

> #### Manage contacts
>
> You can manage your contacts at [www.google.com/contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts).

[Source](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067585) (under *Add email addresses*).

Comment: This is a serious shortcoming. Can't believe they've overlooked such basic task!

Comment: **Still** impossible. Unbelievable.

Comment: How is it possible that such basic functionality remains unchanged after such a long time with 1000s of developers at their disposal?

Comment: Still not possible to add a contact from an email in the inbox app. Unbelievable.